# MySQL Replication VS Mirroring and how to do both?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-replication, mirroring, database-mirroring

MySQL Replication VS Mirroring and how to do both, does anyone knows some information on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL Replication: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APAmsHAYUiI

So replication it is one way relationship: Master to Slave.

Mysql:

1. Stop Slave: `stop slave;`
2. Tell the Slave that it is a Slave and where to locate the Master:

Mysql:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO 
MASTER_HOST = '192.168.1.111', 
MASTER_USER = 'master_replication_user', 
MASTER_PASSWORD =  'master_password', 
MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'DESKTOP-MASTER-PC-bin.000978', 
MASTER_LOG_POS = 678;
```

3. Start Slave:     `start slave;`
4. Check Slave Status: `show slave status;`

---

---

MySQL  Mirroring: https://www.ryadel.com/en/mysql-master-master-replication-setup-in-5-easy-steps/

The main point here is: There are two Masters (so they like a slave to each other, but they will never admit it). You just tell Master A that it is slave of the Master B. And then you tell Master B that he is the slave of Master A. It is reciprocal relationship.

1. Stop Master A: `stop slave;`
2. Stop Master B: `stop slave;`

3.Tell the Master A where to locate the Master B

```
CHANGE MASTER TO 
MASTER_HOST = '192.168.1.111', 
MASTER_USER = 'master_b_replication_user', 
MASTER_PASSWORD =  'master_b_password', 
MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'DESKTOP-MASTER-B-PC-bin.000756', 
MASTER_LOG_POS = 888;
```

4.Tell the Second Master where to locate the First Master

```
CHANGE MASTER TO 
MASTER_HOST = '192.168.1.112', 
MASTER_USER = 'master_a_replication_user', 
MASTER_PASSWORD =  'master_a_password', 
MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'DESKTOP-MASTER-A-PC-bin.000001', 
MASTER_LOG_POS = 777;
```

Mysql:

5.Master A:                    `start slave;`

6.Master B:                   `start slave;`

7.Check Master A Status:       `show slave status;`

8.Check Master B Status:      `show slave status;`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32487266)

Comment: Good point. I will try to  include the essential parts. Thank you!

Comment: I think it is better now)